# ERROR: syntax error at or near "%" when creating a table column variable

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to create a composite type which contains a variable of table column type as below

```
create type gp_core.rec_key_transaction as(
    CODE_TRANSACTION transaction_.CODE_TRANSACTION%TYPE
);
```

I get the below error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "%"
LINE 2: ...       TYPE_TRANSACTION   TRANSACTION_.TYPE_TRANSACTION%TYPE
                                                          


SQL state: 42601
Character: 99
```

I have no idea what could be the problem...

Comment: `%type` and `%rowtype` are only available in PL/pgSQL.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the error is, that the syntax simply isn't supported.

If you want to create type where one attribute is a record of a "table type", there is no need for the `%type` to begin with. For every table (and view) a type with the same name is created. So if `transaction_.code_transaction` is an existing table, you can create your type as:

```
create type gp_core.rec_key_transaction as
(
  CODE_TRANSACTION transaction_.CODE_TRANSACTION
);
```

---

But I honestly fail to see the usefulness of this approach. Why not just use the "table type" directly instead of wrapping it with another type?

Comment: transaction_.CODE_TRANSACTION is a column the table name is transaction_ and the column name is CODE_TRANSACTION , I want the type of the column CODE_TRANSACTION from the table transaction_

Comment: Actually, this is an oracle code that I need to transform to Postgres so the reason I am creating the type is to be able to access it from anywhere under the schema where it is created since in Oracle it was a package global variable.

Comment: Well, you don't need to create a global type for a table in Postgres.